# SXA Dropdown Filter populates with words separated by space

Tags: sxa-search

Have a requirement to provide a filter on news articles for Author.

Created a dropdown filter based on a facet (which is based on a BlogAuthor template field which is of type single line text).

Now filter populates with author names separated out by spaces in them.

How can I populate filter with 'Author 1', 'Author 2' etc. I am using SOLR for search indexes.

[image: Template design]

[image: Facet definition]

[image: Dropdown filter]

[image: Blog article data]

[image: Rendering on the page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue by updating SXA SOLR index by adding following.
It seems single-line-text fields get stored as text_general so making it stored as a string brings back value as a whole and not separated by spaces.

```
<fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
  <field fieldName="blogauthor" returnType="string" />
</fieldTypes>
```

Thanks to Maarten from Sitecore slack community channel for suggestion.